# CUDA device Quadro K620 has insufficient GPU memory

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ethminer

I am new to Ethereum and wanted to clarify whether mining is possible if the graphics card has below the required amount of stated memory and it is part of a mining pool?

I use ethminer and the current about is below:

```
m 20:21:22 ethminer ethminer 0.16.1
m 20:21:22 ethminer Build: linux/release
cu 20:21:22 ethminer Using grid size: 8,192, block size: 128
i 20:21:22 ethminer Configured pool eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999
i 20:21:22 main     Selected pool eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999
i 20:21:22 stratum  Stratum mode detected: ETHPROXY Compatible
i 20:21:22 stratum  Logged in!
i 20:21:22 stratum  Established connection with eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999 at  [213.32.29.168:9999]
i 20:21:22 stratum  Spinning up miners...
i 20:21:22 cuda-0   No work. Pause for 3 s.
i 20:21:22 stratum  Job: #1400d2d3… eth-eu1.nanopool.org [213.32.29.168:9999]
i 20:21:22 stratum  Pool difficulty: 10.00K megahash
i 20:21:22 stratum  New epoch 218
i 20:21:22 stratum  Job: #1400d2d3… eth-eu1.nanopool.org [213.32.29.168:9999]
i 20:21:25 cuda-0   Initialising miner 0
cu 20:21:25 cuda-0   Using device: Quadro K620 (Compute 5.0)
i 20:21:25 stratum  Job: #190ef95a… eth-eu1.nanopool.org [213.32.29.168:9999]
m 20:21:27 ethminer Speed 0.00 Mh/s gpu0 0.00 [A0] Time: 00:00
cu 20:21:29 cuda-0   Set Device to current
cu 20:21:29 cuda-0   CUDA device Quadro K620 has insufficient GPU memory. 1.952 GB of memory found, 2.703 GB of memory required
i 20:21:30 stratum  Job: #748103e2… eth-eu1.nanopool.org [213.32.29.168:9999]
m 20:21:32 ethminer Speed 0.00 Mh/s gpu0 0.00 [A0] Time: 00:00
m 20:21:37 ethminer Speed 0.00 Mh/s gpu0 0.00 [A0] Time: 00:00
m 20:21:42 ethminer Speed 0.00 Mh/s gpu0 0.00 [A0] Time: 00:00
i 20:21:43 stratum  Job: #a12a5e4b… eth-eu1.nanopool.org [213.32.29.168:9999]
i 20:21:46 stratum  Job: #ea5fdad2… eth-eu1.nanopool.org [213.32.29.168:9999]
```

As you will see the speed is always zero. The current command I use to initiate mining is:

```
~/ethminer/bin/ethminer -U --cuda stratum1+tcp://<mywalletaddress>@eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999/w1
```

If there is a way I can mining work on my PC I would appreciate your suggestions. Please let me know if you require more information.

The OS I running on is an Ubuntu Mint Cinnamon 4.15.0-36-generic.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, mining is not possible with your card. You have 2GB, but you need 4GB. Your card is too old for mining.

Comment: Hi Nulik, Many thanks for the confirmation! Does that mean in that in the near future miners will need to keep upgrading their rigs in order keep within the 'mining business' or else wrap up?